# In std::map<string, AnyDataType>, how is the key stored?

Tags: c++, stl

What basically I want to know is that if key is stored as:

1. String itself, in that case comparison will take a lot of time.
2. Hashed value, in that case the BST searching may not be correct, because the hashed values of strings may not be in same sorted order as the strings themselves.

Comment: Why do you think string comparison takes a lot of time? Most string comparisons are approximately O(1), unless they are equal, or share a prefix which is a significant portion of their length. But most strings aren't equal, and don't share a prefix which is a significant portion of their length.

Comment: Actually, that is what my concern was?
That for a string of length m, in worst case it will take O(m) to compare, and the total time to access the data will be O(mlog(n))

Comment: If your `m` ever gets so large that this becomes an issue, this is the wrong container perhaps. Anyhow, you are free to define a different key type. That said, check out the `element_type` of `std::map`, it will answer your question. BTW: Did you actually measure the "lot of time" that string comparisons will take?

Comment: Ok, so in the end, it is straight forward string comparison.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

`template < class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>, class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T> > > class map;`

You can see that `std::map` template can have up to 4 arguments, but only 2 is required. The third one is the Comparison object, which is what is used by `std::map` to compare and order its elements by its `Key`. By default, `map` uses the `less<Key>` object, which in TL:DR words, does the same as `<` operator.

Here is its definition in case you are curious:

```
template <class T> struct less {
  bool operator() (const T& x, const T& y) const {return x<y;}
  typedef T first_argument_type;
  typedef T second_argument_type;
  typedef bool result_type;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> What basically I want to know is that if key is stored as:
>
> 1.String itself, in that case comparison will take a lot of time.

As above.  (`std::map<>` does not use hash values for anything).  Whether it takes a lot of time depends on the number of same-length strings with long shared prefixes: could be bad for e.g. same-length filenames in the same - deeply nested - directory.  You can customise the comparison function if you like (e.g. to compare backwards, or do a quick check for unequal strings by comparing N evenly-spaced characters along the string).  If you have a serious problem with string comparison speed, may also want to consider a `map<string, map<string, X>>` where the outer `string` is the known long and heavily-shared prefix.  Storing a type that wraps a `string` alongside a hash value
helps identify mismatched strings quickly, and if the hash is high quality it may even be practical to use it as if collision free for equality.

Other containers are worth a look too.